# Book recommendation needed: asymptotic behavior of non-stationary Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Is there any stochastic process textbook which covers some standard results for non-stationary Markov chain? For my purpose, countable state space is enough. Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about what kind of Markov chain it is and what kind of results you're looking for.

Comment: Continuous-time or discrete-time chains?